# SonarQube 6.7.2 doesn't start because of PLSQL

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-plugin

We upgraded from SonarQube 5.6 to 6.7.2 and also manually upgraded the plugins, including SonarPLSQL from 2.8 to 3.2.0
We are using the community version but have a valid (paid) licence for the plugin. When trying to start we get the error:

```
org.sonar.updatecenter.common.exception.PluginNotFoundException: The plugin 'license' required by 'plsql' is missing.
```

When removing the plugin from the plugins-folder SonarQube starts without problems.

Can you please help us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way licenses work have changed in the latest LTS. This is why you've got this error.

As you have a valid license of the PLSQL plugin, this means that you are a SonarSource customer so you should get in touch the SonarSource Sales representative you are in contact with to sort this out.